# Best way to import csv data into a game？

Tags: c#, csv

I have a bunch of csv files which contains different types of data entries. Now I want to load these csv files in a game-readable manner, say, lists of entries. And keep a balance between performance and memory usage.
I have comed up with several ways of doing this:

1. Parse the required csv file at runtime. Ideally the csv data is parsed just before it is needed at some point when parsing does not introduce a lag, e.g. during scene loading.
2. I can parse them offline, and generate a file like this:

```
public class ContentOfSomeCsv {
    private static data;
    public static LoadData(){
        data = new EntryType[] {
            entry1,
            entry2,
            ...
            entryn,
        }
    }
}
```

3. Import the csv file into a runtime database, load the required entry(s) from database and cache if needed.

I have tried the first approach with a not-so-smart parser implementation. Scene loading takes significantly longer. So I want to switch to approach 2 or 3. But I'm not sure if these approaches work.

I want to know when should I use the approaches above and if there is any problem with them. Or is there better ways to import csv files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel ;) While Unity does not have a CSV library onboard (assuming that's the engine you use), there is a widespread open source implementation:
https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper
Tutorial: https://zetcode.com/csharp/csv/
For usage in Unity you would not call the "dotnet add package CsvHelper" line but instead just download the code from Github and insert it into your assets folder.

As for which one of your approaches is the right one, depends a bit on the usecase and the amount of data.

Use 2. (conversion into own file):
If you know you only need a known, small fraction of the data from the original CSV. Since CSV is text based, reading every entry will be just as fast as from a custom file.
Technically you can speed up things with binary formats that do not require parsing values from text, but that's rather advanced.
EDIT: I misunderstood this approach. Thought it would be an external file, not actually generating a C# file itself with data in it.
While I don't know whetehr real downsides would occur, it just breaks the principle of separating data from code. There is usually no need for this.

Use 3. (database):
If the original data is large (>50k entries) and you need to do complex "queries" at runtime like associate different fields in the CSV etc.
Loading into a database will probably not be faster than loading into memory.

Otherwise use 1. (simple reading on game start up). That works just fine for most game applications.
What exactly means "significantly longer"?

By the way, one mroe option would be to use Excel or Open office to filter your CSV for the data and export a new CSV with just what you need. That might be the most flexible approach and prevent you from needing to come up with your own file format.

Comment: I have seen people against writing data into csharp files. One point is bad scalability, which can be minimized if the files are generated. I'm not sure about this. Could you explain whats the problem with approach 2 when applied on large data? Is it related to memory usage and gc or something?

Comment: @TinglePan Please define what "large data" is for you, just so we can talk with some common ground. You can calculate the amount of memory quite easily since you know how much a float (usually 32 bytes), int (usually 16 bytes) etc. needs. GC is not as much of an issue if you only read a single time, because you can reduce GC impact by not using a dynamically growing data structure but a fixed array instead which you create in one go (so there is only one single memory alocation - dynamic structures re-allocate regularly).

Comment: Ah, I kinda misunderstood how you mean #2. Thought that would be about exporting and then reading a diferent .txt file. Not a C# file. Hmm, I cannot talk from experience there. It's definitely something that is usually not being done. Technically there should not be a higher memory or GC impact than if you'd read the same data from a .txt or .csv.
--- 
I could imagine however that some IDEs which interpret the files, won't like it when a C# file is really massive!
I'd rather suggest what I thought you meant: Write out a smaller .csv\.txt and read that one. Or do you need all data?